# Wanting to make a new input/text box when I click a button

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

TIA for any help. I am trying to create a new field when I click a button. This is for a to-do list project. I tried to make a function that would create the new field. Then after creating the function I put it into an .eventListener when the button was clicked. I am not sure where to go from here.

Here is my code

[text](https://codepen.io/byrd9612/pen/eYogwXR)

**Javascript **

```
const button = document.querySelector('.createnew')
const field = document.querySelector('.field');

 function newField() {
 const inputElement = document.createElement("input.value");
 inputElement.setAttribute("type", "text");
  return field.appendChild(inputElement); 
 }

 button.addEventListener('click', newField);
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>To-Do</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="header">To-Do List</h1>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="form">
            <input class="field" type="text" placeholder="Input Text">
            <input class="check" type="checkbox">
        </div>  

        <button class="createnew">Add New Field</button>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is document.createElement("input.value") supposed to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understood your task properly, it can be achieved as shown below.

In your initial code, you've tried adding a new input as a child to the existing input, which doesn't seem right because you need to add a new input into the form instead.

Please let me know if this helps.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.createnew')
const form = document.querySelector('.form');

function newField() {
  const inputElement = document.createElement("input");
  inputElement.setAttribute("type", "text");
  inputElement.setAttribute("class", "field");
  inputElement.setAttribute("placeholder", "Input Text");
  form.appendChild(inputElement);

  const checkboxElement = document.createElement("input");
  checkboxElement.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  checkboxElement.setAttribute("class", "check");
  form.appendChild(checkboxElement);
}

button.addEventListener('click', newField);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(32, 65, 105, 0.656);
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}

.field {
  background-color: rgb(233, 222, 222);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border: none;
  width: 700px;
  height: 15px;
}

::placeholder {
  color: black;
}

.createnew {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>To-Do</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="header">To-Do List</h1>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="form">
      <input class="field" type="text" placeholder="Input Text">
      <input class="check" type="checkbox">
    </div>

    <button class="createnew">Add New Field</button>
  </div>




  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey @user23669013, if my answer was helpful, don't you mind picking it as a correct?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am new to stack overflow, so sorry for not marking it as correct at first. I didn’t realize that was an option. I really appreciate you taking the time to look at the problem though. This helped me a lot!